# how to place an text on the top center position image responsively using css?

Tags: html, css, css-float

Please see this html .

```
 <div class="parent">
    <div>
      <span id='chn'> motrolla</span>  
      <img id="roller" src="images/motrolla.png">
     </div>
    </div>
```

I write media query to make this parent div responsive. I need to display the span just top of the image and make it as center position  . How to do this ? Currently the name shown under the image  .

Comment: It already top of the image, did you mean inside of the image or outside of the image?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div>
    <span id='chn'> motrolla</span><br/>
    <img id="roller" src="images/motrolla.png">
  </div>
</div>


.parent div{
    text-align:center;
}
```

[Here is the **JSfiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/cdL9q3wn/)